# d3.js - throttle events on hover?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an event listener in D3 such that whenever the user hovers on the graph, we grab the data from the point being hovered on, and update various legends on the page.

Here's the code (it's part of a bigger Backbone application):

```
var Hover = Component.extend({

events: function () {
  if (this.modernizr.touch) {
    return {
      'touchstart .hover': 'onTouchStart'
    };
  } else {
    return {
      'mousemove .hover': 'onMouseMove'
    };
  }
}, ...

onMouseMove: function (e) {
  var offset = this.graph.graphWrapper.offset();
  var scaleFactor = this.graph.scaleFactor();
  var x = (e.pageX - offset.left) / scaleFactor - this.margin.left;
  var y = (e.pageY - offset.top) / scaleFactor - this.margin.top;

  this.attachBodyListener('mousemove');
  this.selectPoint(x, y);
  return false;
},

selectPoint: function (x, y) {
  // do various calculations etc here. 
}

});
```

This works well on fairly sparse graphs, but on dense graphs, I find that when I move the mouse, the event is triggered hundreds of times, which makes it feel very laggy.

Is there a way I can set an event for "on mouse move end" or similar? Or that I could throttle events, without setting a delay and making the graph feel laggy for a different reason?

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-mousestop-event/blob/master/jquery.event.mousestop.js Is this the best approach, or is there something simpler?

Comment: Unless you can narrow it down to specific elements that should be "active", the link you've just posted seems like the best option. There's certainly nothing built into D3 that would allow you do this.

Comment: Oh and the other option would be to not limit the events, but not handle all of them (I suspect that this is where the lag comes from), e.g. with a counter or timer.

Comment: Underscore.js has both throttle and debounce functions. If you can afford a few extra bytes, highly recommended

Comment: @StephenThomas I'm already using Underscore as part of Backbone, so that's really helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've got Underscore,

```
    onMouseMove: _.throttle(function (e) {
        // ...
    }, 1000),
```